# Equivalent measures and their supports

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am trying to come up with a two discrete probability measures on $(R, B(R))$ with the same support, but not equivalent. I came up with the two probability measures $M$ and $N$, with $M(X=\frac{1}{n}) = p_n > 0$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$, $M(X=0)=p_{\infty} = 0$ and $\sum_{n} p_n=1$, while $N(X=0)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $N(X=\frac{1}{n}) = q_n > 0$ with $\sum_{n} q_n=1$. I then showed that the support of these two probability measures are $\left\{0,1,2,\cdots\right\}=N$, but if we choose $A=(-2,0]$, then $M(A)=M(X=0)=0$ while $Q(A)= Q(X=0)=\frac{1}{2}>0$. Thus, $M$ and $Q$ are not equivalent even when they have the same support.

**My question:** Could anyone please help let me know if my proof above is valid?

Comment: Is the support $\mathbb N$, or the reciprocals of the natural numbers $\frac{1}{n}$, along with zero in both cases? After clarifying that, your proof is good, Although it could have been much simpler.

Comment: If you put a positive mass at each rational number you get a discrete probability measure whose (topological) support is the entire real line. It is not equivalent to the standard Gaussian measure, for example. Just thought you might be interested in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need $$\sum_n q_n=\frac12$$ and the support is $$\left\{\frac1n\middle|\ n\in\mathbb N\right\}\cup\{0\}.$$

Otherwise this seems okay.

Comment: My bad. Many thanks for your review.